# How does Swift prevent certain generic overloads, like Range.subscript for integer types?

Tags: generics, swift, overloading

The documentation of Swift for the type `Range` states:

> Like other collections, a range containing one element has an
>   `endIndex` that is the successor of its `startIndex`; and an empty
>   range has `startIndex == endIndex`.
>
> Axiom: for any `Range` `r`, `r[i] == i`.
>
> Therefore, if `T` has a maximal value, it can serve as an `endIndex`, but can never be contained in a `Range<T>`.
>
> It also
>   follows from the axiom above that `(-99..<100)[0] == 0`. To prevent
>   confusion (because some expect the result to be `-99`), in a context
>   where `T` is known to be an integer type, subscripting with `T` is a
>   compile-time error::
>
> ```
> // error: could not find an overload for 'subscript'…   
> println( Range<Int>(start:-99, end:100)[0] )
> ```
>
> However,
>   subscripting that range still works in a generic context::
>
> ```
> func brackets<T:ForwardIndexType>(x: Range<T>, i: T) -> T {
>   return x[i] // Just forward to subscript
> }
> println(brackets(Range<Int>(start:-99, end:100), 0)) // prints 0
> ```

How can we achieve this kind of behavior in our own generic classes? I can't understand how it works just from the definition of `subscript`:

```
subscript (position: T) -> T { get }
subscript (_: T._DisabledRangeIndex) -> T { get }
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code behaves as the same as builtin `Range`.

```
struct MyRange<T: ForwardIndexType> {
    subscript (position: T) -> T {
        return position
    }
    subscript (_: T._DisabledRangeIndex) -> T {
        fatalError()
    }
}

MyRange<String.Index>()["foo".startIndex] // no problem
MyRange<Int>()[0] // < [!] error: could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

It seems that `Int._DisabledRangeIndex` is `Int`, and `Int16._DisabledRangeIndex` is `Int16` and so on.

When `T._DisabledRangeIndex` is identical to `T`, `MyRange<T>` eventually have 2 conflicting `subscript` definition that causes compilation error.

Comment: Looks like you're right. If `subscript` is overloaded like this, it gives the error message you mentioned. If another method (e.g. `foo`) is overloaded like this, the error message is “Ambiguous use of ‘foo’”. Funny that they're different.